# How to create a sheet under a specific folder with google API for python?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I am able to create a sheet with the code below in the root of ‘My Drive’ but how do I create the sheet under a folder in “My Drive” or “Shared drives”?

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

service = build(‘sheets’, ‘v4’, credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
body = {}
results = sheet.create(body=body).execute()
pprint(results)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- You want to create new Spreadsheet in the specific folder.
- You want to achieve this using google-api-python-client with python.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

### Issue:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, new Spreadsheet cannot be directly created to the specific folder of Google Drive using Sheets API. In this case, Drive API is required to be used.

### Sample script:

Before you run the script, please set the folder ID.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the new Spreadsheet is directly created to the specific folder in your Google Drive. In order to create Spreadsheet, the mimeType of `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet` is used.

Script:

```
drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
file_metadata = {
    'name': 'sampleName',
    'parents': ['### folderId ###'],
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
}
res = drive.files().create(body=file_metadata).execute()
print(res)
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, after the new Spreadsheet is created by Sheets API, the Spreadsheet is moved to the specific folder in your Google Drive.

Script:

```
# Create Spreadsheet to the root folder.
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
body = {}
results = sheet.create(body=body).execute()
pprint(results)

# Move the created Spreadsheet to the specific folder.
drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
folderId = '### folderId ###'
res = drive.files().update(fileId=results['spreadsheetId'], addParents=folderId, removeParents='root').execute()
print(res)
```

### Note:

- For both samples, please add a scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`. And when the scopes are added, please remove the created credential file including the refresh token and authorize again. By this, the additional scopes are reflected to the refresh token.
- If you want to use the shared Drive, please modify as follows.

  - For pattern 1

    - `file_metadata = {'name': 'sampleName','parents': ['### folderId ###'],'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet','driveId': "###"}`
    - `res = drive.files().create(body=file_metadata, supportsAllDrives=True).execute()`
  - For pattern 2

    - `res = drive.files().update(fileId=results['spreadsheetId'], body={'driveId': "###"}, addParents=folderId, removeParents='root', supportsAllDrives=True).execute()`

### References:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @bayman Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: If I'm using `body = {"properties": {"title": "title_here"}, "sheets": sheetsObj}
    res = sheets.spreadsheets().create(body=body).execute()
    print(res)`, where do I insert the argument for folder ID?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just have to comment that pattern 1 works for shared folders without setting "driveId". The supportsAllDrives: true is sufficient