# How to specify where in google drive the sheets API creates a new spreadsheet with the spreadsheets.create() method?

Tags: google-sheets-api

How to specify *where* in google drive the sheets API creates a new spreadsheet when using the [spreadsheets.create()](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/create) method (am assuming this is the correct method to be using since [docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) show it requires Drive OAuth scope to use)?

Am using the [python API libs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python#step_2_install_the_google_client_library) referenced in the google docs (and the [create() example](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/create) for this lib is not very detailed). Looking at the [Spreadsheet request body template](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet) for the API call, there is nothing that seems like it is the place to indicate *where* in Drive you want to new Spreadsheet to be created.

Anyone with more experience know how to do this? Any examples out there to use as reference?

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58107431/7108653

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, thanks. Marking this as duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for your response.